# ¿Como se puede incrementar un valor por cada registro insertado en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

quisiera soliciar su apoyo con agluna idea, estoy intentanto pasar datos de dos tablas relacionadas por el campo Numero a otras dos tablas parecidas (es necesario porque son diferentes modulos) pero al momento de pasar necesito obtner un nuevo numero de Poliza e ir incrementantolo por cada registro, me inserta los datos correctamente en las dos tablas, pero con el mismo numero de poliza en todos los registros.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Bancos].[traslado]
@Empresa AS INT,
@EmpresaConta AS INT,
@FechaInicio AS DATE,
@FechaFinal AS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Poliza INTEGER
    DECLARE @contador INTEGER
    
    SET @contador=0
    SET @Poliza = 0
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Bancos.PolizaEncabezado 
                    WHERE EstadoPoliza = 1
                    AND TrasladoContable <> 1 
                    AND Empresa =@Empresa
                    AND FechaContable >= @FechaInicio
                    AND FechaContable <= @FechaFinal)
        BEGIN
            --INSERTAR EL ENCABEZADO DE LAS POLIZAS
            SET @Poliza = (SELECT MAX(Numero) FROM Sistema.TipoDocumento WHERE idEmpresa=@EmpresaConta AND Codigo=2)
            SET @Poliza += 1
            --INSERTAMOS EL ENCABEZADO
            INSERT INTO Contabilidad.PolizaEncabezado(Empresa, FechaContable, Numero, FechaRegistro, DescripcionEmpresa, ValorPoliza, EstadoPoliza, DescripcionPoliza, TipoPoliza, EmpresaOrigen, PolizaOrigen)
            SELECT encabezado.Empresa, encabezado.FechaContable, @Poliza, encabezado.FechaRegistro, encabezado.DescripcionEmpresa, encabezado.ValorPoliza, encabezado.EstadoPoliza, 
                encabezado.DescripcionPoliza + ' Ref. ' + CAST(encabezado.NumeroDocumentoMovimiento AS varchar), encabezado.TipoPoliza, encabezado.EmpresaOrigen, encabezado.Numero
            FROM Bancos.PolizaEncabezado encabezado
            WHERE encabezado.EstadoPoliza = 1 AND encabezado.TrasladoContable <> 1 AND encabezado.Empresa = @Empresa AND encabezado.FechaContable >= @FechaInicio AND encabezado.FechaContable <= @FechaFinal
            ORDER BY encabezado.FechaContable, encabezado.Numero
            --INSERTA EL DETALLE DE LAS POLIZAS
            INSERT INTO Contabilidad.PolizaDetalle( Numero, Empresa, Cuenta, FechaContable, Correlativo, FechaRegistro, EmpresaOrigen, Debe, Haber)
            SELECT @Poliza, @Empresa, detalle.Cuenta, encabezado.FechaContable, detalle.Correlativo, encabezado.FechaRegistro, detalle.EmpresaOrigen, detalle.Debe, detalle.Haber
            FROM Bancos.PolizaDetalle detalle
            INNER JOIN Bancos.PolizaEncabezado encabezado ON detalle.Empresa = encabezado.Empresa AND detalle.Numero = encabezado.Numero AND detalle.FechaContable = encabezado.FechaContable
            WHERE detalle.Debe >= 0 OR detalle.Haber >= 0
            ORDER BY detalle.Numero, detalle.Haber, detalle.Correlativo
            --SE ACTUALIZA EL ESTADO DE LA POLIZA EN EL BANCO
            UPDATE Bancos.PolizaEncabezado
            SET TrasladoContable = 1, FechaTraslado = GETDATE()
            WHERE EstadoPoliza = 1 
                AND TrasladoContable <> 1 
                AND Empresa=@Empresa 
                AND FechaContable >=@FechaInicio 
                AND FechaContable <=@FechaFinal
            --SE ACTUALIZA EL CONTADOR    
            SET @contador = @contador+@@ROWCOUNT
        END
    RETURN @contador
END
GO
```

Comment: Hola Javier, veo muchas cosas raras o que faltarían en tú código, ¿podrías dar un poco más de contexto? ¿Por que necesitas generar un nuevo número?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes valerte de la función de ventana [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) para ir incrementando el valor para cada fila insertada.

Por ejemplo, en la sentencia `insert/select`, en lugar de hacer

```
select @Poliza, @Empresa...
```

que provoca que todas las filas insertadas tengan el valor de la variable `@Poliza`

Podrías ir sumando el número de fila a esa variable en cada registro devuelto por el select:

```
select   @Poliza + row_number() over (order by alguncampo) - 1
       , @Empresa...
```

Dado que `row_number()` va a devolver una secuencia basada en 1, y supongo que quieres que el primer registro tenga el valor que ya está en la variable @Poliza, le voy restando 1 en cada fila. Si este no es el caso, quita la resta.

Answer (score 0):

Javier, sería una ayuda que incluyeras un poco más de información sobre tu base de datos y el resultado o salida de la operación que estás ejecutando, como por ejemplo cuál es el número de Póliza repetido que este procedimiento te está insertando en todos los registros.

A juzgar por el código de tu procedimiento, el problema puede estar en la declaración de la variable `@Poliza` y su **inicialización** en 0 antes del **bucle WHILE**. Creo que deberías inicializar la variable con el valor máximo actual de la tabla Sistema.TipoDocumento para el código de documento 2 de la empresa especificada por argumento `@EmpresaConta`. Si no se inicializa con el valor correcto, la secuencia de números de póliza será incorrecta y se repetirá en cada inserción de datos.

El problema se plantea en la declaración siguiente:

```sql
SET @Poliza = (SELECT MAX(Numero) FROM Sistema.TipoDocumento WHERE idEmpresa=@EmpresaConta AND Codigo=2)
```

Al realizar esta asignación dentro del bucle WHILE, se ejecutará en cada iteración llamando a la base de datos y obteniendo el valor máximo de `Numero` en cada repetición. Así, cada vez que se inserten registros en las nuevas tablas, se insertarán con el mismo número de póliza, que será el número máximo de póliza disponible en ese momento.

Al mover la declaración fuera del bucle, la consulta solo se ejecuta una vez, obteniendo el valor máximo de `Numero`, almacenándolo en la variable `@Poliza` y practicando el incremento del valor de ésta en cada iteración/inserción, asegurando que cada póliza tenga un número identificador único:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [Bancos].[traslado]
@Empresa AS INT,
@EmpresaConta AS INT,
@FechaInicio AS DATE,
@FechaFinal AS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Poliza INTEGER
    DECLARE @contador INTEGER
    
    SET @contador=0
    
    -- Obtener el valor máximo actual de la tabla de Sistema.TipoDocumento para el código de documento 2 de la empresa de contabilidad especificada
    SET @Poliza = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Numero), 0) FROM Sistema.TipoDocumento WHERE idEmpresa=@EmpresaConta AND Codigo=2)
    
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Bancos.PolizaEncabezado 
                    WHERE EstadoPoliza = 1
                    AND TrasladoContable <> 1 
                    AND Empresa =@Empresa
                    AND FechaContable >= @FechaInicio
                    AND FechaContable <= @FechaFinal)
        BEGIN
            SET @Poliza += 1
            --INSERTAMOS EL ENCABEZADO
            INSERT INTO Contabilidad.PolizaEncabezado(Empresa, FechaContable, Numero, FechaRegistro, DescripcionEmpresa, ValorPoliza, EstadoPoliza, DescripcionPoliza, TipoPoliza, EmpresaOrigen, PolizaOrigen)
            SELECT encabezado.Empresa, encabezado.FechaContable, @Poliza, encabezado.FechaRegistro, encabezado.DescripcionEmpresa, encabezado.ValorPoliza, encabezado.EstadoPoliza, 
                encabezado.DescripcionPoliza + ' Ref. ' + CAST(encabezado.NumeroDocumentoMovimiento AS varchar), encabezado.TipoPoliza, encabezado.EmpresaOrigen, encabezado.Numero
            FROM Bancos.PolizaEncabezado encabezado
            WHERE encabezado.EstadoPoliza = 1 AND encabezado.TrasladoContable <> 1 AND encabezado.Empresa = @Empresa AND encabezado.FechaContable >= @FechaInicio AND encabezado.FechaContable <= @FechaFinal
            ORDER BY encabezado.FechaContable, encabezado.Numero
            --INSERTA EL DETALLE DE LAS POLIZAS
            INSERT INTO Contabilidad.PolizaDetalle( Numero, Empresa, Cuenta, FechaContable, Correlativo, FechaRegistro, EmpresaOrigen, Debe, Haber)
            SELECT @Poliza, @Empresa, detalle.Cuenta, encabezado.FechaContable, detalle.Correlativo, encabezado.FechaRegistro, detalle.EmpresaOrigen, detalle.Debe, detalle.Haber
            FROM Bancos.PolizaDetalle detalle
            INNER JOIN Bancos.PolizaEncabezado encabezado ON detalle.Empresa = encabezado.Empresa AND detalle.Numero = encabezado.Numero AND detalle.FechaContable = encabezado.FechaContable
            WHERE detalle.Debe >= 0 OR detalle.Haber >= 0
            ORDER BY detalle.Numero, detalle.Haber, detalle.Correlativo
            --SE ACTUALIZA EL ESTADO DE LA POLIZA EN EL BANCO
            UPDATE Bancos.PolizaEncabezado
            SET TrasladoContable = 1, FechaTraslado = GETDATE()
            WHERE EstadoPoliza = 1 
                AND TrasladoContable <> 1 
                AND Empresa=@Empresa 
                AND FechaContable >=@FechaInicio 
                AND FechaContable <=@FechaFinal
            --SE ACTUALIZA EL CONTADOR    
            SET @contador = @contador+@@ROWCOUNT
        END
    RETURN @contador
END
GO
```

He incluido una llamada a la función de T-SQL `ISNULL(expresión, valor_sustitutivo)` para manejar el caso en que tu tabla Sistema.TipoDocumento pudiera estar vacía, inicializando la variable `@Poliza` en tal caso en 0.